# ASP.NET using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I am learning ASP.NET by examples from the book on C# and that book was written at time when AutoMapper supported the method Initialize. I tried to circumvent it but not successfully. I replaced :

```
//    Mapper.Initialize(
  //    cfg =>
  //    {
  //      cfg.CreateMap<Inventory, Inventory>()
  //.ForMember(x => x.Orders, opt => opt.Ignore());
  //    });
```

with:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Inventory, Inventory>()
       .ForMember(x => x.Orders, opt => opt.Ignore()));
```

and it seems (at least do not show errors in VS 2019).

But in the following:

```
// GET: api/Inventory
[HttpGet, Route("")]
public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetInventory()
{
    var inventories = _repo.GetAll();
    return Mapper.Map<List<Inventory>, List<Inventory>>(inventories);
}
```

I get an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mapper.Map<Inventory, Inventory>(Inventory)

Can somebody help me? Thanks. I am a newcomer here. Jiri

Comment: To be able to determine where the mapping is going wrong it would be useful to see the `Inventory` type.

Comment: namespace AutoLotDAL.Models
{
    [Table("Inventory")]
    public partial class Inventory:EntityBase
    {
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PetName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        = new HashSet<Order>();

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
return Mapper.Map<List<Inventory>>(inventories);
```

Comment: Thank you anyway, but it does the same error.

Comment: I have use Automapper same way but I built the separate displayModel like this.           var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
              {
                  cfg.CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductDisplayModel>();
              });

Comment: var productList = _productEndPoint.GetAll();                                                                    var products=Mapper.Map<List<ProductDisplayModel>>(productList);